# Using replaceAll to ignore plurals, capitals, and punctuation?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that replaces words in this sentence I made up with whatever the user wants the word to be replaced with:

> "The duck quacked at the ducks dancing. Happy ducks! Sad Ducks!"

But, the problem is in I don't know how to replace the versions of duck with capitals, plurals, punctuation (duck, ducks, ducks!, Ducks!, etc)

I currently have this version but all it does is replace "duck", I'm not sure how to do the other variations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String story = "The duck quacked at the ducks dancing. Happy ducks! Sad Ducks!";

    System.out.println("What word do you want replaced?");
    String replaceWord = keyboard.nextLine();

    story = story.replaceAll("\\bduck\\b", replaceWord);

    System.out.println(story);
}
```

Comment: On a side note: Your program logic seems a bit off, you ask *"What word do you want replaced?"* but you only replace "duck". Shouldn't use ask two questions *"What word do you want replaced?"* and then *"What word should replace [word]?"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using `replaceAll` to ignore plurals, capitals, and punctuation?

You have already managed punctuation well by surrounding the pattern with `\\b`.

To ignore capitals (ignore case), you can prefix the pattern with `(?i)`, like this:

```
story = story.replaceAll("(?i)\\bduck\\b", replaceWord);
```

To handle plurals... That's language specific, and typically very irregular.
If you want to handle something like that, then you will need a dictionary of singular and plural forms. Even then, there may be false negatives of some exceptional words.

Comment: cool thank you! Do you think if I wanted to do plurals I could just have multiple replaceAll's to handle those versions? I'm using Java by the way

Comment: There won't be a perfect solution for handling plurals. But you could use multiple `replaceAll` to handle the most common cases.